# Filtering and Grouping tuples on several fields in Pig Latin

Tags: join, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am relatively new to using Pig for my work. I have a huge table (3.67 Mil Entries) with fields -- *id, feat1:value, feat2:value ... featN:value*. Where *id* is text and feat_i is the feature name and *value* is thevalue for the feature *i* for a given *id*. 
The number of features may vary for each tuple since its a sparse representation.

For example this is an example of 3 rows in data

1. id1   f1:23    f3:45   f7:67
2. id2   f2:12    f3:23   f5:21
3. id3   f7:30    f16:8   f23:1

Now the task is to group queries that have common features. I should be able to get those set of queries that have any feature overlapping. 
I have tried several things. *CROSS and JOINS* create explosion in data and reducer gets stuck. Im not familiar with conditioning GROUP BY command.

Is there a way to write a condition in GROUP BY such that it selects only those queries that have common features.
For the above rows result will be:

1. id1, id2
2. id1, id3

Thanks

Comment: In your example, where do id2 and id3 have common features?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I just corrected the answer.

Comment: There is no operation in PIG which can work across rows. A JOIN or CROSS is inevitable in this case. Other solution is to use UDF and pass all your data to the UDF as a single row. In the UDF as well, you would end up doing JOIN (2 loops over the data), so I dont see any performance improvement in using UDF. 
IMO, SelfJoin of a relation containing 3.6M rows is not that huge for Hadoop.

Comment: I tried self join, it just sits there, with 1 reducer. I will try to run it with PARALLEL. Would doing this on Map-Reduce work better, because I spent last two days doing this, with a cluster of 12 nodes, and enough memory and still not get cosine similarity!

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an elegant way to do this in pig. There is no possibility to group b based on some condition.

However, you could GROUP ALL your relation and pass it to a UDF that compares each record with every other record. Not very scalable and a UDF is required, but it would do the job.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate pairwise similarity between all these rows. Again using CROSS explodes the size of the data (3.6 * 3.6 Mil). I just need pairwise similarity between id1, id2 and id1, id3 and id2, id3. I thought filtering it by common features will make the N^2 problem manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and not parse the string.
If its possible, read the data as two columns: the ID column and the features columns.

Then I would cross join with a features table. It would essentially be a table looking like this:

```
f1
f2
f3
```

etc

Create this manually in Excel and load it onto your HDFS.

Then I would group by the features column and for each feature I would print all IDs

essentially, something like this:

```
features = load ' features.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (feature_number:chararray);

cross_data = cross features, data;

filtered_data = filter cross_data by (data_string_column matches feature_number);

grouped = group filtered_data by feature_number;
```

Then you can print all the IDs for each feature.

The only problem would be to read the data using something other than Pig storage.
But this would reduce your cross join from 3.6M*3.6M to 3.6M*(number of features).